# What should I do with this question?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked this question awhile ago:

[Is this a correct natural deduction proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808962/is-this-a-correct-natural-deduction-proof)

I naively did not account for the deduction system I was using not being used much broadly speaking.

A good answer was given but it did not work for me, so am I correct in not accepting the answer?

Following this question, every question I asked on this topic (Natural Deduction) listed the specific rules I was using and a resolution to the question was always reached.

The two options I am thinking of to resolve this question:

1. Editing the question to list the specific system rules I am using, then leaving it open to see if anyone else answers. Self answering if no one does, as I know the answer now. (I'm unsure of this due to there being an upvoted answer already).
2. Just accepting the answer given (I'm unsure of this because it doesn't work for the system used in question).

Comment: There is no obligation to accept any Answer on your Question.  If the Answer seems well-researched and otherwise merits acknowledgement, but it did not actually help you, you can upvote much as any other Community member might.  Accepting an Answer is your prerogative as the one who posted the Question, but is not an obligation.

Comment: If editing the question would invalidate the existing answer, it would be best not to do that. Self-answering is fine, even though there is already an upvoted answer. You can also accept your own answer.

Comment: @MattSamuel You should turn that into an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If editing the question would invalidate the existing answer, it would be best not to do that. Self-answering is fine, even though there is already an upvoted answer. You can also accept your own answer.

Comment: Thank you, self answering was the route I chose to resolve this question.